# Change style of references when using \begin{thebibliography}

Tags: bibliographies

I am working on a joint paper and we've been using the `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` to define the references, however, the editors have requested the order of the references to change to `unsrt`.

I am aware how to do this when using an external `.bib` file but how do I change this using the `\begin{thebibliography}` method?

Comment: manually, by hand.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- the question is clear.  for good or ill, the authors have not used a `.bib` file, so it's too late.

Comment: @Johannes_B I assume you mean to copy and paste the individual `bibtiem` blocks in the order I need?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Everybody as she/he wishes ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is primarily the sort of scenario for which BibTeX was created.  Programs like BibTeX (and now BibLaTeX/biber) generate the bibliography environment for you.  When you use `{thebibliography}` yourself, you bypass the sorting and special handling these tools provide.

Your obvious next step is to manually reorder the entries, but this may not be the best use of your time.  I would consider creating a BibTeX database from the references you're working with.  (Yes, this also must be done by hand -- but can be greatly expedited with editor macros.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I normally us BibTeX but when I joined work on this paper the `thebibliography` was already in use and I wasn't aware of its limitations.

Comment: @Colin747 oh I'm not saying it's your fault :-) we all inherit ugly code at some point or another, but fixing it to 'do the right thing' is probably your most powerful solution.

Comment: Isn't that the truth! I think it'll be my first port of call for the first revision!